# A query to export the DDL of all the tables in a schema

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have more then 250+ table in my schema, I want to export them as DDL ( create table ...) and send have them in one script . Useally I used the export tool from PLSQL Developer.

But I am facing errors like sql export cannot take clob or long raw or long or blob so i have to remove manually about 50 table.

Is there a query for that?. Because the other way in PLSQL Developer is really slow.

Comment: there is no such thing as "the export tool from plsql". PL/SQL is a programming language and does not have "an export tool".

Comment: then I have to correct it and say PLS/sql developer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', table_name)
from user_tables
```

You can exclude tables if you want to:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', table_name)
from user_tables
where table_name not in ('FOO', 'BAR');
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE "L_O11"."_REASONS"
   ( "COMP

when I used your query, I had only the first creation column

Comment: @Moudiz: then your tool doesn't retrieve (or display) the full result.

Comment: i am using pl/sql developer , what tool you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the ancient IMP/EXP tool, when you specify just schema and no data.

e.g. from Tom Kyte's solution [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3a%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1464804639878):

```
exp userid=/ owner=some_schema
imp userid=/ indexfile=foo.sql
```

and then get rid of these lines

```
REM  ...
CONNECT
```

and then remove all the other `REM`s.

Comment: you mean in plsql tool --> export ? If yes I am facing errors as i meantioned above . becase there are table have long and clob. I am not able to do that with anciant way due columns have data type such long and clob